# Implementing automatic notifications for android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app (Android App programmed in Java) that has all Firebase as the backend which has Firestore, real-time database, auth, etc 
Now the app requires me to send notifications to the user when he receives a message or more precisely when a group in which the user has a message from someone the user should get a notification something like *” You have got a message”*. 
Chats are managed in Firebase Realtime Database 
How can I implement this if I am not planning to use paid services for this?

PS: Using the free plan in Firebase for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the app requires me to send notifications to the user when he receives a message or more precisely when a group in which the user has a message from someone the user should get a notification something like ”You have got a message”.

You can achieve that using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). Please also note, that there 3 ways in which you can send notifications:

- To single devices
- To groups of devices
- To devices subscribed to topics

So according to the use case of your app, you might consider using the second or the third one.

> How can I implement this if I am not planning to use paid services for this?

Firebase Cloud Messaging [is free of charge](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). So there is nothing that you should pay. If you however need to send lots of notifications, then I recommend you to watch [Best practices when sending FCM messages at scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FY9_5H39sYQ).

Besides that, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will also help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).

Comment: Can i automate in cloud messaging to send notifications whenever new messages come in group ( realtime database)?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can do that. I recommend you follow the steps explained in the official documentation and if you have a hard time implementing them, then please post a new question, here on StackOverflow with what you have tried that doesn't work the way you expect, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.